# Incorrect output with std::time_put and %#c

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have written a program that uses std::time_put to format a time stamp using the locales as follows:

```
typedef std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > iterator_type;
typedef std::time_put<char, iterator_type> time_put_type;
time_put_type const &tp = std::use_facet<time_put_type>(out.getloc());
struct tm std_time;
iterator_type begin(std::cout);
char const format[] = "#%c";

// std_time is set to a time stamp from the data received
tp.put(begin, std::cout, ' ', &std_time, format, format + strlen(format));
```

When the windows computer is configured to use the Brasilian Portuguese locale, I am getting an output for this similar to: "quarta-feira, 29 29e junho 29e 2016 12:00".  I would expect output like "quarta-feira 29 de junho 2016 12:00" instead.  This appears to be a bug in the visual c++ standard library but there may be something wrong with the way time_put is being invoked.  Has anyone else seen behaviour like this or aware of a work-around?

I poked around some more in the regional and language settings for the operating system.  I found that the "long date" format defined by the operating system is

```
dddd, d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy
```

Looking at the resulting date that comes from this rule, it would look like the OS or standard library is not honouring the single quotes within the string and is interpreting the d character in "de" as the day of the month.

Comment: Sound like it might be time for a Microsoft bug report (if this is really wrong; I cannot evaluate the correctness of this - not from Brasil).